# Unimplemented desc = unknown service pb.AuthService Error on my simple authentication server

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, rpc

I created a simple authentication server with Golang. This is my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package auth;

option go_package = "./pkg/pb";

service AuthService {
    rpc Register(RegisterRequest) returns (RegisterResponse) {}
    rpc Login(LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
    rpc Validate(ValidateRequest) returns (ValidateResponse) {}
}

// Register
message RegisterRequest {
    string name = 1;
    string surname = 2;
    string email = 3;
    string password = 4;
}
message RegisterResponse {
    int64 status = 1;
    string error = 2;
}

// Login
message LoginRequest {
    string email = 1;
    string password = 2;
}
message LoginResponse {
    int64 status = 1;
    string error = 2;
    string token = 3;
}

// Validate
message ValidateRequest {
    string token = 1;
}
message ValidateResponse {
    int64 status = 1;
    string error = 2;
    int64 userID = 3;
}
```

I have 2 file, auth_grpc.pb.go and auth.pb.go

I want register myself with my client but when I make this request this error comes.
I looked everywhere for pb.AuthService but I don't have this function or instance.

This is my main.go file :

```
func main() {
    env, err := config.LoadConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("FAILED AT CONFIG: ", err)
    }

    h := db.Init(env.DBUrl)

    jwt := utils.JwtWrapper{
        SecretKey:       env.JWTSecretKey,
        Issuer:          "go-grpc-auth-svc",
        ExpirationHours: 24 * 365,
    }

    s := services.Server{
        H:   h,
        Jwt: jwt,
    }

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterAuthServiceServer(grpcServer, &s)

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", env.Port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to listing:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("start gRPC server on %s", lis.Addr().String())

    if err := grpcServer.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to serve:", err)
    }
}
```

and auth.go file. I tryed to implement jwt and DB handler:

```
type Server struct {
    H   db.Handler
    Jwt utils.JwtWrapper
    pb.UnimplementedAuthServiceServer
}

func (s *Server) Register(ctx context.Context, req *pb.RegisterRequest) (*pb.RegisterResponse, error) {...}
```

I tried to register with my client and my client file is as simple as my server.

My service client struct :

```
type ServiceClient struct {
    Client pb.AuthServiceClient
}
```

My main.go file :

```
func main() {
    c, err := config.LoadConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed at config: ", err)
    }

    // ROUTER INSTANCE
    router := gin.Default()

    // MIDDLEWARES
    router.Use(middlewares.ErrorHandler)

    auth.RegisterRoutes(router, &c)

    router.Run(c.Port)
}
```

And register routes file :

```
func RegisterRoutes(r *gin.Engine, c *config.Config) *ServiceClient {
    svc := &ServiceClient{
        Client: InitServiceClient(c),
    }

    routes := r.Group("/auth")
    routes.POST("/register", svc.Register)
    routes.POST("/login", svc.Login)
    fmt.Println(svc)
    return svc
}

func (svc *ServiceClient) Register(ctx *gin.Context) {
    routes.Register(ctx, svc.Client)
}

func (svc *ServiceClient) Login(ctx *gin.Context) {
    routes.Login(ctx, svc.Client)
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this error is coming when you start your client? Share the code for your client as well.

Comment: I updated the question. Do you need more information about client? @BurakSerdar

Comment: What I asked was how you connected the grpc server. I am assuming that's when you get the error, right?

Comment: @BurakSerdar when i post the /auth/register, it Dial with `cc, err := grpc.Dial(c.AuthSvcUrl, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))` then I'm using `pb.AuthServiceClient.Register()` service you can check it on [github-link](https://github.com/barankibar/shopicity-svc-gateway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your github repo (because there was no obvious issue in the code you posted).

In the [client`auth.proto`](https://github.com/barankibar/shopicity-svc-gateway/blob/main/pkg/auth/pb/auth.proto) you specify:

```
package pb;
```

But in [the service](https://github.com/barankibar/shopicity-auth-svc/blob/main/pkg/pb/auth.proto) it's:

```
package auth;
```

So the error `unknown service pb.AuthService` is due to the fact that your server is providing `auth.AuthService` (and not the `pb.AuthService` your client is expecting). Change your `.proto` files so they are consistent (or, ideally, reference the same files).